# String Interpolation doesn't work, no error is shown

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolation

The problem is that the string interpolation isn't working, but when I use json pipe, it shows the object data. It`s really frustrating and in other components the interpolation works well, so I reallt can't understand what is the problem on my code.

Here is the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Category } from 'category';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/category.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cat-detail',
  templateUrl: './cat-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cat-detail.component.css']
})
export class CatDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  category: Category;
  constructor(private _categoryService: CategoryService,
              private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategory();
  }

  getCategory() {
    const id = +this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this._categoryService.getCategoryById(id)
        .subscribe(data => this.category = data);
  }
}
```

this is the template:

```
<h1>Details</h1>
<ul>
  <li>_id: {{category._id}}  </li>
  <li>category: {{category.category}}</li>
</ul>
```

I'll be thankful for any help! thanks.

Comment: Try `{{category?._id}}` and `{{category?.category}}`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan tried it, didnt work..

Comment: what do you get when you console.log the response of `data =>`  ??

Comment: @NadhirFalta I get the full object, and again as I said, when I use {{ category | json }} it shows the object as a json, but when I want to show only the strings, it seems to not work.

Comment: @TomerKrichli can you post a sample of what you get ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta [{…}]
0: {_id: 1, category: "Real Estate", __v: 0}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: @NadhirFalta now I see that the "data" returns an array with 2 objects. I solved it by adding the fix: this.category = data[0]. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TomerKrichli yes that's it the data passed didn't match the interpolation structure. you can use an ngFor for that too if you wanna display all.